# Can banach spaces be taught without introducing the Metric space first?

Tags: functional-analysis

In our curriculum in france we dive head first in the topology of banach spaces probably to set a standing ground for approaching series and sequences of functions,integrable function(includes dependence on a parameter),power series.
and i was wondering whether there was a book that is compatible with our curriculum.

Comment: I would say that learning about metric spaces before banach spaces is recommended. Many of the metric space topology results are used when proving theorems about Banach spaces

Comment: alright, but which book do you recommend?

Comment: What topics are you familiar with? Assuming you are French, and have a solid real analysis background, I recommend "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations" by Haim Brezis. The author (who is originally French) published a translation in English and it is very good. I am sure the French version is just as good if not better.

Comment: Interestingly enough you never need to talk about Cauchy sequences in Banach space theory. eg you can take as defintion of completeness the condition that a space is isomorphic to its bidual via the canonical map.

Comment: eh i think there is a misunderstanding,i'm a second year and this is our very first experience into "functional analysis" or whatever it is o.o so far we've only did calculus,some abstract algebra and linear algebra

Comment: actually there is no mentions of functional analysis in our curriculum, it's just stated topology of banach space, sequences and series of functions,integrable function(dependence on a paramater),power series.